# Symfony2 open stream_socket_client()

Tags: php, symfony, ssl

I tried to open an ssl connection in symfony2.
So, I created a service which calls the `stream_socket_client()` method but the connection failed.

I do not know if is possible to open a connection in a service?

Comment: Yes, it is possible. Show some code.

Answer (score 0):

```
        // Create SSL context
        $ctx = stream_context_create();

        // Opening PEM file
        $pathCk = $this->kernel->locateResource('@MyBundle/path/ck.pem');
        stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'local_cert', $pathCk);

        // Opening connection with apple servers
        $fp = stream_socket_client('ssl://gateway.push.apple.com:2195',
        $err, $errstr, 60, STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT, $ctx);
```

I had this error message :

> Unable to connect to ssl://gateway.push.apple.com:2195 (Network is
>   unreachable)

Comment: I have a bit more to isolate the problem. The connection fails when I call the service from the console but it works well if I call from a controller.

Have any ideas?